# NDSolve, Schrödinger equation, and decaying solution

Tags: numerical-integration, differential-equations, physics

I am trying to solve a Schrödinger equation for a particle hitting a step potential using `NDSolve` in Mathematica. Here is my code:

```
mu = 6.;
m = mu;
R  = 5.;
Vs2 = 4./(2*m*R^2);
Vs = -10./(2*m*R^2) + Vs2;
Energy = 0.001
VCC[r_] = Vs*UnitStep[R - r] + Vs2*UnitStep[r - R];
L = 0;

system = {RC''[r] + 
 2/r*RC'[r] + (-L*(L + 1)/r^2 - 2*mu*(VCC[r] - Energy))*RC[r] == 
0, RC[0.001] == 1.0, RC'[0.001] == 0.0 };

syssol = NDSolve[system, {RC[r]}, { r, 0.001, 1000.}, MaxSteps -> 10000000];

Plot[Evaluate[{RC[r]} /. syssol], {r, 0.001, 200.0}, PlotRange -> {-1.1, 1.1}]
```

There should be decaying wave when particle hits the potential step, but `NDSolve` gives an increasing result. I am sure there is some trick to fix this, so I am waiting for you help.

Comment: Before posting this question, you should first have followed the advice in the comments to your identical question on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855619/ndsolve-schrodinger-equation-and-decaying-solution

Comment: What is your `m` ? Also take a look at this (it's a bit different case but you can see how everything is set up): http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ScatteringOverPotentialStep/

Comment: By the way, this has exact solutions, so I'm guessing this could be a homework problem and hence not appropriate for this forum.

Comment: you forgot to define `m` here (this is to make it simpler for someone to cut and paste this code directly)

Comment: and, the root of you problem is mathematical, not an error in programming. did you try to do it analytically, for instance?

Answer (score 12):

[noeckel’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855619/ndsolve-schrodinger-equation-and-decaying-solution) on StackOverflow is spot on. This is not a Mathematica issue, this is a mathematical issue. Namely, Mathematica is giving you the correct solution to the system of differential equation and boundary conditions given. The conditions given (and in particular the derivative imposed at the origin) are incompatible with the expected decay. Bear in mind that, at $r \geq 5$, your wavefunction will have two components of the form $\exp(\alpha r)$ and $\exp(-\alpha r)$. For each set of boundary conditions, you get a different linear combination of these two, and the only conditions that make sense are those for which the diverging term is zero.

Comment: +1. If memory serves me well, usual conditions for the radial wave function are the absence of increasing exponent at infinity and finiteness at zero (or at least, convergence of the integral of `Abs[f[r]]^2` over the volume around zero. The divergence of this integral would correspond to the classical fall-on-the-center scenario, for potentials ~ `1/r^a` with `a > 2` IIRC). This rules out fixing the derivative at zero, as you said, and fixing the w.f. value itself does not make sense either, since it is fixed by w.f. normalization (that is, unless I forgot everything, it's been a while :))

Comment: sorry guys, m = mu. Also, I guess this is not exactly mathematical issue because mathematica does not realize bounded problems (f''(r)-k^2*f(r)==0 type problems), so you have to tune one of the parameters (energy, potential etc.) in order to get decaying solution. I am able to do that up to r=50-60, but I would like to get it for farther distance.

Comment: By the way, I have an analytic solution for this type problem, and my purpose is to compare my analytic result to numerical calculation. This is not homework.